# Macro output as an input in subsequent pythontex command/environement?

Tags: python, exercises

I am trying to make a document with one specific math/physics exercise. Of course the exercise consists of input data (i.e. a = 2 cm, b = 3 cm,...) and part where calculations are performed.

Just by changing the inputs (e.g. a = 4 cm) I want to produce a new document, where all calculations made would be updated automatically. To this end I am using pythontex package.

I have managed to produce calculations in python where variables are explicitly defined from start, e.g. `a + b` (1st calculation). How can I save the result `a + b` in new variable `z` and use `z` in subsequent calculation under python, e.g. `z + a`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\mysum}[2]{#1 + #2}
\newcommand{\mysumpy}[2]{\py{#1 + #2}}

\begin{document}
Here are the inputs:\\
\pyc{a_py = 2}  $a = \py{a_py}$ cm\\
\pyc{b_py = 3}  $b = \py{b_py}$ cm\\

Here is my 1st calculation:\\
\begin{equation}
z = \mysum{a}{b} = \mysumpy{a_py}{b_py}
\end{equation}

Here is my 2st calculation involving previous result ("z"):\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `\mysumpy` command to take an optional argument that is the name of the variable in which the result should be stored.  I'm using the `etoolbox` package (which `pythontex` already loads) to see if an optional argument is present.  Then you can access the value of the variable later using `\py`.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\mysum}[2]{#1 + #2}
\newcommand{\mysumpy}[3][]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\py{#2 + #3}}%
    {\pyc{#1 = #2 + #3}\py{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Here are the inputs:\\
\pyc{a_py = 2}  $a = \py{a_py}$ cm\\
\pyc{b_py = 3}  $b = \py{b_py}$ cm\\

Here is my 1st calculation:\\
\begin{equation}
z = \mysum{a}{b} = \mysumpy[z_py]{a_py}{b_py}
\end{equation}

Here is my 2nd calculation involving previous result (``z''): \py{z_py}\\
\end{document}
```

If you are going to do a lot of similar calculations, you might also consider creating some more compact commands to save typing.  And if you are going to be using units, you might consider using the `siunitx` package.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\pyinputval}[2]{%
  \pyc{#1 = #2}%
  \ensuremath{#1 = \SI{#2}{cm}}}
\newcommand{\pysum}[3][]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\ensuremath{#2 + #3 = \py{'\\SI{0}{{cm}}'.format(#2 + #3)}}}%
    {\pyc{#1 = #2 + #3}%
      \ensuremath{#1 = #2 + #3 = \py{'\\SI{0}{{cm}}'.format(#1)}}}}

\begin{document}
Here are the inputs: \\
\pyinputval{a}{2} \\
\pyinputval{b}{3} \\

Here is my 1st calculation:\\
\begin{equation}
\pysum[z]{a}{b}
\end{equation}

Here is my 2nd calculation involving previous result (``z''): \py{z}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: I particularly like the second variant with `siunitx` package. However, the next (crucial) step is enabling nesting of (different) arithmetic operations. In this way, relative complex calculation can be performed and formatted at the same time. Obviously, `\pysum[z]{a}{\pysum{a}{b}}` is not working. 
I am assuming, the problem would be much simpler without formatted equation (e.g. `a + b` part), but it is quite useful for educational purposes. Is it possible to achieve this?
Thanks for providing this great package!

Comment: @KlemenD It might be best to ask a new question with more detail about what your exercises look like and what types of calculations are needed. If you asked a new question with an example of the sort of nesting you want, or at least an example of the output you are trying to create, it would be easier to find a solution.